# ESP8266 Driver for waveshare 2.9 e ink

Tags: driver, display, esp8266, spi, e-ink

I'm looking for a driver for the E-Ink display from [waveshare](http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/2.9inch_e-Paper_Module)

I can find drivers for Arduino and Raspberry-PI. Is there also a driver for ESP8266. Currently, I'm trying to understand the Arduino driver and create an own driver for the ESP8266, but as I am a java developer I'm not a good c developer.

I hope anyone can help me, thanks!

Comment: The code from the page you posted seems to be sufficient. Have you tried flashing it in? If yes what happened?

Comment: Thank you. I've tried it with the driver and it works!!! Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The driver works also for the ESP8266 (I am using the Nodemcu v3). I've used the following pin-mapping in EPD_drive_gpio.h:

```
#define CS D8
#define EPD_CS_0    digitalWrite(CS,LOW)
#define EPD_CS_1    digitalWrite(CS,HIGH)
#define isEPD_CS  digitalRead(CS)

#define RST D3
#define EPD_RST_0   digitalWrite(RST,LOW)
#define EPD_RST_1   digitalWrite(RST,HIGH)
#define isEPD_RST digitalRead(RST)

#define DC D2
#define EPD_DC_0    digitalWrite (DC,LOW)
#define EPD_DC_1    digitalWrite (DC,HIGH)

#define BUSY D1
#define isEPD_BUSY digitalRead(BUSY)
#define EPD_BUSY_LEVEL 0

extern void SPI_Write(unsigned char value);
extern void driver_delay_xms(unsigned long xms);
#endif
```